# Hover effect on a different element

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this structure:

HTML

```
<div class="bottom-container">
    <div class="double-arrow"></div>
    <div class="bottom-box green margin-top">
        <h1 class="bottom-box-h1">Box title 1</h1>
        <p class="bottom-box-text">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The .bottom-box-text isn't displayed on default. It has a display:none property.

I need to display the .bottom-box-text div when I hover over the .double-arrow div. But I cant figure it out.

I have this CSS:

```
.double-arrow:hover .bottom-box-text {
    display: inline;
}
```

I tried different selectors (like "+"  "~"), but it doesn't work.

Thank you if you can help!

Comment: you need to first target the parent element `.bottom-box`

Comment: Sorry for beeing dumb, but how exactly can I do that?

Comment: `.double-arrow:hover + .bottom-box .bottom-box-text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use general sibling selector to select `.bottom-box` first:

```css
.bottom-box-text {
    display: none;
}

.double-arrow:hover ~ .bottom-box .bottom-box-text {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-container">
  <div class="double-arrow">Arrow</div>
  <div class="bottom-box green margin-top">
    <h1 class="bottom-box-h1">Box title 1</h1>
    <p class="bottom-box-text">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.double-arrow:hover + div > .bottom-box-text { 
  display: inline;
}
```

Basically, when the double arrow is hovered, the div right after is selected and its children having `.bottom-box-text` will have the effect applied. If it doesn't, you'll maybe have to use `!important` as an attribute on `display`.